# How to install d3dx9_43?

Tags: wine

In order to use a certain Windows program on Wine, I need to install d3dx9_43 (a Directx driver) but I am not sure how to.

Without this, it gives me this error:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x004d65f6).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:004d65f6 ESP:0033f4e8 EBP:0033f8b4 EFLAGS:00210282(  R- --  I S - - - )
 EAX:80040154 EBX:00000000 ECX:00000000 EDX:80040154
 ESI:051bb020 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0033f4e8:  00000000 0033f8c8 004def49 0033f8c8
0x0033f4f8:  0000ac44 42680000 fffffffe 0033f8c8
0x0033f508:  00000001 1d339300 0033f530 7e8fa000
0x0033f518:  7e9af4cb 7ea4a000 0033fa04 0001007e
0x0033f528:  051bb020 7e9ce1ee 0000000c 00000000
0x0033f538:  00000001 0033f56c fffffffc ffffffd6
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit rw-
Backtrace:
=>0 0x004d65f6 in emulator (+0xd65f6) (0x0033f8b4)
  1 0x004e7f46 in emulator (+0xe7f45) (0x0033fdd0)
  2 0x0047d083 in emulator (+0x7d082) (0x0033fe60)
  3 0x7b85e5cc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe78)
  4 0x7b85f653 in kernel32 (+0x4f652) (0x0033feb8)
  5 0x7bc799b0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
  6 0x7bc7c93d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  7 0x7bc7998e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  8 0x7bc4e8fe call_dll_entry_point+0x7ed() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
  9 0xf75e150d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  10 0xf75e15cb wine_switch_to_stack+0x2a() in libwine.so.1 (0xffcd8b78)
  11 0x7bc541e2 LdrInitializeThunk+0x3a1() in ntdll (0xffcd8bd8)
  12 0x7b865bdd __wine_kernel_init+0xa0c() in kernel32 (0xffcd9cf8)
  13 0x7bc547a3 __wine_process_init+0x192() in ntdll (0xffcd9d88)
  14 0xf75dec70 wine_init+0x30f() in libwine.so.1 (0xffcd9de8)
  15 0x7bf00fdc main+0xfb() in <wine-loader> (0xffcda238)
  16 0xf73f9a83 __libc_start_main+0xf2() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x004d65f6: movl    0x0(%edi),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (119 modules)
PE    400000- 1135000   Export          emulator
PE  10000000-101e5000   Deferred        d3dx9_42
ELF 79e40000-7b7fa000   Deferred        libllvm-3.4.so.1
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7c0a8000-7c0e9000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7c0b0000-7c0e9000   \               usp10
ELF 7c6f0000-7c727000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7c748000-7c76a000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7c770000-7c78d000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c880000-7c88f000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7c890000-7cc6b000   Deferred        libgallium.so.0
ELF 7cc90000-7d07a000   Deferred        r600_dri.so
ELF 7d090000-7d0ae000   Deferred        libcgmanager.so.0
ELF 7d0b8000-7d0d0000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
ELF 7d2c0000-7d2cd000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d2d0000-7d2d3000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d2d8000-7d2df000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d2e0000-7d2e4000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d2e8000-7d2ec000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d2f0000-7d2f6000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d2f8000-7d310000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d310000-7d313000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d318000-7d330000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7d330000-7d390000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d398000-7d3ab000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7d3b0000-7d3d5000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d3c0000-7d3d5000   \               imm32
ELF 7d4f0000-7d520000   Deferred        p11-kit-trust.so
ELF 7d520000-7d529000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d530000-7d537000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d538000-7d53d000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d540000-7d558000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d558000-7d55c000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d560000-7d5ab000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d5b0000-7d5ec000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d5f0000-7d604000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d608000-7d68f000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d690000-7d69c000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d6a0000-7d6d0000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d6d0000-7d78e000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d790000-7d7a2000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d7a8000-7d86e000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d870000-7d8b5000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d8b8000-7d925000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d928000-7d92c000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d930000-7d943000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7d948000-7d97f000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d950000-7d97f000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d980000-7d986000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d988000-7d993000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d998000-7d99d000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d9a0000-7d9ae000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d9b8000-7d9c3000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d9c8000-7d9d9000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d9e0000-7d9e4000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d9e8000-7d9ef000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d9f0000-7d9f4000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d9f8000-7da1a000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7da20000-7db54000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7db58000-7db6b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7db70000-7db7b000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7db80000-7db86000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7db88000-7db8c000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7db90000-7dc22000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dba0000-7dc22000   \               winex11
ELF 7dce8000-7dd11000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd18000-7dd53000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dd78000-7dda0000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dda0000-7ddba000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ddc0000-7de60000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de80000-7dec0000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7de90000-7dec0000   \               winspool
ELF 7dec0000-7df3a000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ded0000-7df3a000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7df40000-7e173000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7df50000-7e173000   \               shell32
ELF 7e178000-7e263000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e180000-7e263000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e268000-7e29e000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e270000-7e29e000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e2a0000-7e348000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e2b0000-7e348000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e348000-7e3c9000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e350000-7e3c9000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e3d0000-7e50c000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3f0000-7e50c000   \               ole32
ELF 7e510000-7e52c000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e520000-7e52c000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e530000-7e63f000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e550000-7e63f000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e640000-7e780000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e650000-7e780000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e780000-7e7bd000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e790000-7e7bd000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e7c0000-7e832000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7d0000-7e832000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e838000-7e955000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e840000-7e955000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e958000-7eab2000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e970000-7eab2000   \               user32
ELF 7eab8000-7ebbf000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7ebbf000   \               comctl32
ELF 7ebc0000-7ebcd000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ebd0000-7ebdc000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ebe0000-7ebf9000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec08000-7ec22000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ec10000-7ec22000   \               version
ELF 7ef98000-7efde000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7eff0000-7eff9000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f73e0000-f7590000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7590000-f7595000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7598000-f75b4000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75d8000-f778d000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7790000-f77b2000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77b9000-f77ba000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001b    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001a    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
00000024 (D) H:\Desktop\Sega Model 2\emulator.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.13.0-39-generic
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how to fix this?

Thank You very much in advance :)

P.s. If it helps at all, the program I want to use is a .exe - It doesn't need an installation, also, some sources have said that I have got to use Winetricks to fix this, but how?

Update: I installed d3dx9_43.dll, but now I get this error in the console when I load a rom:

fixme:thread:start_thread Started native thread 00000024
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32eea8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d:swapchain_init The application requested more than one back buffer, this is not properly supported.
Please configure the application to use double buffering (1 back buffer) if possible.
fixme:d3d9:Direct3DShaderValidatorCreate9 stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {3eda9b49-2085-498b-9bb2-39a6778493de} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {3eda9b49-2085-498b-9bb2-39a6778493de} could be created for context 0x1
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address 0x4d65f6 (thread 0009), starting debugger...

Comment: I think it's similar running `regsvr32 d3dx9_43.dll` via cmd line as administrator privilege if I remember correctly. How to do? Download your `d3dx9_43.dll` and paste it into system32 folder. then open cmd as admin and run above command to register the .dll.

Comment: Nope, that hasn't worked, the program still crashes when I try to use a rom

Comment: If you are unable to install DirectX, then how do you know installing it will fix the page fault?

Answer (score 4):

Install `winetricks`:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

#### The short way

Depending on whether your have a custom `WINEPREFIX`,`WINEARCH`, etc., export them. If you don't know what these mean, don't worry, you can ignore them. Now run:

```
winetricks d3dx9_43
```

#### The long way

You can also use the Winetricks GUI:

- Select default wineprefix: [image: Select default wineprefix]
- Select "Install Windows DLL or component": [image: Select "Install Windows DLL or component"]
- Select `d3dx9_43`: [image: Select <code>d3dx9_43</code>]
- Now it will download the DirectX package, which is a few hundred MBs, so go have a cup of coffee if you don't have a fast connection:
  [image: Downloading...]

Comment: I've done that, but the program still isnt working, I loaded it through the terminal, when I load a rom it gives me another error, Ive added it to the post above

Comment: @Leethom Most likely the program doesn't work in Wine.

Comment: According to the Winedb, the program should work under Wine